Doit-on écrire "de la façon dont" ou "de la façon que"?

Salut Georges. C'est Lucien. Est-ce que Gaston t'a, en passant, parlé de la façon dont je lui ai parlé au meeting ?

Salut Georges. C'est Lucien. Est-ce que Gaston t'a, en passant, parlé de la façon que je lui ai parlé au meeting ?


Avons-nous affaire à un cas de redondance de de avec l’emploi de dont ?

L’existence de la préposition de « cachée » dans dont impose certaines contraintes dans l’emploi de ce pronom. Il faut en effet éviter d’utiliser dont lorsque l’antécédent, c’est-à-dire le nom que remplace dont et qui le précède immédiatement, est lui-même déjà lié à la préposition de.
On distingue ainsi trois cas de redondance de de avec l’emploi de dont.
C’est de + dont ne doit pas être utilisé: avec l'antécédent de dont introduit par la préposition de. C’est le cas notamment dans une phrase principale qui commence par C’est lorsque la subordonnée est introduite par dont.
Pour éviter le pléonasme, si on emploie la préposition de devant l’antécédent dans la phrase principale, on choisit le pronom relatif que ensuite dans la subordonnée, et non pas dont. On peut aussi, tout simplement, enlever le de.
C’est de cette voiture que j’ai envie. (ou : C’est cette voiture dont j’ai envie; et non : C’est de cette voiture dont j’ai envie)
https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22904/la-grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-relatifs/le-pronom-relatif-dont

Vos deux phrases sont aussi ambiguës l'une que l'autre à cause des deux occurrences de parler dans des acceptions différentes. Est-ce que Gaston t'a, en passant, dit de quelle façon je lui ai parlé au meeting ? est une reformulation possible. Est-ce que Gaston t'a, en passant, parlé de la même façon que je lui ai parlé au meeting ? en est une autre, non moins compatible et de sens différent.

La première phrase signifie que Gaston a discuté avec Georges de la manière dont Lucien lui a parlé lors du meeting : Lucien a parlé à Gaston d'une façon particulière et Gaston rapporte cet événement à Georges. C'est largement la phrase la plus vraisemblable.
La deuxième phrase peut être une variante de la première dans un registre très relâché et souvent fustigé.
D'autre part, la deuxième phrase pourrait éventuellement signifier que Gaston à parlé à Georges de la même manière que Lucien a parlé à Gaston durant le meeting, c'est à dire qu'il a reproduit la façon de parler particulière de Lucien face à Georges.
Cette interprétation est cependant peu vraisemblable à moins qu'on ne rajoute même :

Est-ce que Gaston t'a, en passant, parlé de la même façon que je lui ai parlé au meeting?

